# Azure Repo - Pipeline - Building Azure Web Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I have created a Azure Function (.csx file) in VSCode and I want to be able to push it to a branch on a Azure Devops Repo and it automatically build and deploy to a Azure Portal Web Function.

I have used the Azure Function VSCode extension but this does not achieve what I require. I want to be able to push it to a repo and let it do the pipeline build.

I have created a pipeline with the "Azure App Service Deploy" Task. As required by the task it is linked to a Service Principal, and has uses Azure Resource Manager. It has a Azure Subscription, Service Name and Resource group.

I have done "Save & Queue", hoping everything was correctly done and I would see the Function on the branch go to the Azure Function I specified in the task however I got a build error saying

"No package found with specified pattern /home/vsts/work/1/s/**/*.zip".

I do not have this file, I was assuming it would try to get the .csx file.

Can anyone lead me in the correct direction, I am lost to where I am failing, is my Azure Function is VSCode wrong, is my manner of pushing missing a step or is my pipeline wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's an example of how I've been doing the builds for azure function:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    versioningScheme: 'off'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    versioningScheme: 'off'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'artifacts'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'QueueFunction'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

and then the release would be:

```
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: 'Azure Function App Deploy'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(subscriptionId)'
    appType: functionApp
    appName: 'xxxxx'
```

so in general, you need to build your application and then package it and push it to the feed. and then you can push the package in the release.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've been using the "gui" side for it, im guessing that is yaml? Seems simple enough to understand though so Thanks... 
Does the VSCode side i've done sound right? as in the fact it is a csx file not a cs or csproj? Also just for my understanding why did you remove where I said thanks in my initial op...

Comment: thats a long story, but basically when I started using this site my posts were edited in the same fashion (hello\thanks\etc removed). they said it doesnt add anything relevant to the question (which is true)

Comment: so from what I know, zipping the function and uploading zip files is considered to be the preferred way, and, say, functions v2 dont allow to use .csx files as of now

Comment: Oh okay, I would have assumed pushing the file to a repo would suffice as it would make sense to have a working copy as in in the repo that would then build in the right manner, thus allowing other devs to just pull updated files should they ever need to update it. Ahh okay guess I'll try to zip it up and see how it goes. Sounds like abit of an awkward way of doing things atm

Comment: well, thats how usually software works, you have source code, your build it, you deploy it ;)

Comment: haha I get that bit, just don't understand the need to zip and then upload the zip files to the repo. I was assuming I could push the .cs pr .csx file and it would build from there.

Comment: i think with zipping you have to have the whole structure in the zip file, not just one individual sub-function, but all the sub-function that are hosted on the function app